# WebGL - Rotating object in the direction it is travelling

Tags: javascript, math, opengl, webgl, three.js

In this example: http://deeplogic.info/project/webGL/

How can I rotate the object in the direction in which it is travelling?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question — do you mean like a wheel rotates as it travels along the ground? If so then I note that the linked example is 2d, do you want to keep it that way or add a third dimension?

Comment: The linked example is in 3d although it is only moving on the 2d plane. So rotating around the z axis. What I want to do is as the rectangle moves in a direction I want it to point in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rotation around z for an object moving in the direction (x, y) you can use the [`Math.atan2(y,x)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan.asp) method. It'll return an angle in radians. The OpenGL convention prior to ES 2 was to work in degrees, but nowadays it's up to whatever code you have to push transformations to the vertex shader. You'll probably want to convert though, in which case just multiply the result by 180 (half a circle in degrees) and divide by pi (half a circle in radians).

Comment: I'm getting tired of those uncalled used for trigonometry. People, com'on linear algebra isn't that hard. See my answer for a more direct approach.

Comment: And I'm tired of results with uncalled for square roots, though I don't expect there's a firm rule for the efficiency of three trig functions (including making the rotation matrix) versus three square roots. Further justifications: people tend to study trigonometry earlier than linear algebra and working through an angle is a more direct and specific answer to a question that invokes the concept of rotation.

Comment: People first doing trigonometry before linear algebra is exactly the problem. Almost every trigonometric problem can be expressed in terms of linear algebra. And in case of rotations, angles just lack some information. The only true way to represent a rotation is by elements of the SU(2) group, which are matrices, quaternions, or in case of 2D complex numbers, which are a subset of quaternions. And in the case of "let it point into direction it moves", you already have the direction vector.

Comment: First doing an atan(x/y), which BTW blows up for 90°, then going back with sin and cos is just missing the point.

Comment: If you look at the code in main.js you will find that I did try both ways although I did not try to convert it back into degrees so that may work. Looking at a tan graph, Im guessing it blows up at 270 as well? If I only allowed rotation +/- 89 would it work?

Comment: The code has been corrected to using atan2 which seems to work, but I wonder if it is best to rotate the object and move it a unit in the angle it is facing rather than translating and rotating

Comment: @Sycren: Yes it blows up whereever cos(a) goes zero; tan(a) = sin(a)/cos(a) – and that is +/- 90° (-90° = 270°)

Comment: @datenwolf: it's not just trigonometry before linear algebra; in the UK at least trigonometry is taught during the period when schooling is obligatory (ie, it's taught prior to age 16) and linear algebra appears only if you opt to continue studying maths for at least another year. So that's just one example of a system where proper, fully educated adults, even those with university degrees, didn't learn trigonometry first, they learnt trigonometry only.

Comment: @Sycren: using atan2 rather than atan automatically deals with cases where the denominator would head towards zero. There's no need to restrict yourself in any way.

Comment: @Tommy: Well, we're dealing with graphics programming here. And that is, face it, 90% linear algebra. Saying people only know of trigonometry and thus they should do it that way is a lame excuse. If you want to program OpenGL properly, you'll need to know your linear algebra. The sooner you learn it, the better.

Comment: I have covered both although I admit that I understand trig a lot easier. Which is more efficient though?

Comment: @datenwolf: it's not really lame at all. A solid grounding in both is useful, especially if you don't conflate computer graphics and OpenGL.

Comment: With the x-y plane special case , likely the linear algebra. Otherwise the trigonometry. But there'll be so limited a difference between the three as to make that the grounds on which to make a decision. The atan2 approach is a single line of code but the linear algebra isn't specialised to the x-y plane and avoids imports trig ideas. I think those are valid grounds for a decision.

Comment: Actually, revise that. I doubt there'd be a sustained advantage across browsers for either approach above linear algebra with an x-y specialisation. Though that'll still be so negligible a difference as not to be a serious concern. To be explicit: while datenwolf and I are having a spirited debate about the value of discussing different approaches, there's no disagreement about the maths. All approaches mentioned are equally valid ways to answer the question set.

Answer (score 3):

Say your object is moving into direction D, then all you need to do is finding a vector perpendicular to that direction. In case your movement is in only one plane you can find this vector E by taking the cross product of D with the plane normal N.

```
E = D × N
```

This yields you with 3 vectors D, E and N. After normalization those form the base of a rotated coordinate system. You can put them into the columns of a 3×3 matrix

```
D_x E_x N_x
D_y E_y N_y
D_z E_z N_z
```

extend this matrix into a 4×4 homogenous one

```
D_x E_x N_x 0
D_y E_y N_y 0
D_z E_z N_z 0
  0   0   0 1
```

and you can pass it to OpenGL with glMultMatrix to apply it on the matrix stack.

Comment: In the specialised case here, where objects are moving along the xy plane, you could go further and get the orthogonal by switching coordinates and negativing one, then take advantage of the (informal) symmetry in the matrix that you're building towards to normalise one vector only.

Comment: @Tommy: If you evaluated taking the cross product of a vector in the XY plane with Z you'll see, that this exactly what's going to happen.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that. The special case is relevant even in a discussion of the general case.