# image rotation in OpenGL atan2?

Tags: c#, opengl, atan2

Any help with this I'm using OpenGL with C#. I cant use any other libraries other than:

```
using System;
using OpenGL;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
```

I cant seem to rotate my image so it faces the way its moving.

This is called in my world draw method:

```
foreach (Bug bug in m_Bugs) 
            {
                double radians = Math.Atan2(bug.getPos().X + bug.getVel().X, bug.getPos().Y + bug.getVel().Y);
                double angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

                GL.glRotated(angle, 0, 0, 1);
                bug.Draw(); 
            }
```

and my draw method is called in the main thread here:

```
form.RegisterDraw(myWorld.Draw);
```

my bug.draw works perefectly it displays and blends the textures fine.

the code in the foreach loop in my world.draw method returns the velociity (getVel) and the position (getPos) as 2d vectors.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

```
private void Load(uint[] array, int index, string filepath)
    {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(filepath);
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapdata;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        /* Set the correct ID, then load the texture for that ID * from RAM onto the Graphics card */
        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, array[index]);
        GL.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)GL.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height, 0, GL.GL_BGR_EXT, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_byte, bitmapdata.Scan0);
        GL.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (int)GL.GL_LINEAR);
        GL.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (int)GL.GL_LINEAR);

        /* This code releases the data that we loaded to RAM * but the texture is still on the Graphics Card */
        image.UnlockBits(bitmapdata);
        image.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Pos + Vel ?

It looks like you need only Pos. So:

```
Math.Atan2( bug.getVel().X, bug.getVel().Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this already in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7288931/524368 quoting in verbatim:

---

Say your object is moving into direction D, then all you need to do is finding a vector perpendicular to that direction. In case your movement is in only one plane you can find this vector E by taking the cross product of D with the plane normal N.

```
E = D × N
```

This yields you with 3 vectors D, E and N. After normalization those form the base of a rotated coordinate system. You can put them into the columns of a 3×3 matrix

```
D_x E_x N_x
D_y E_y N_y
D_z E_z N_z
```

extend this matrix into a 4×4 homogenous one

```
D_x E_x N_x 0
D_y E_y N_y 0
D_z E_z N_z 0
  0   0   0 1
```

and you can pass it to OpenGL with glMultMatrix to apply it on the matrix stack.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, how can I rotate the bug by the angle between the coordinate system and the velocity in code?